# Holding different properties of multiple classes in one class

Tags: c#

I am doing a problem from a book called "C# 7 and .Net Core: Modern Cross-Platform Development - Second Edition" and the exercises given at the end are not provided solutions.

The problem outline:

Create a console application named Ch10_Exercise02 that creates a list of shapes, uses serialization to save it to the filesystem using XML, and then deserializes it back:

```
// create a list of Shapes to serialize 
var listOfShapes = new List<Shape> 
{ 
  new Circle { Colour = "Red", Radius = 2.5 }, 
  new Rectangle { Colour = "Blue", Height = 20.0, Width = 10.0 }, 
  new Circle { Colour = "Green", Radius = 8 }, 
  new Circle { Colour = "Purple", Radius = 12.3 }, 
  new Rectangle { Colour = "Blue", Height = 45.0, Width = 18.0  } 
};
```

Shapes should have a read-only property named Area so that, when you deserialize, you can output a list of shapes, including their areas, as shown here:

```
List<Shape> loadedShapesXml = serializerXml.Deserialize(fileXml)
as List<Shape>; 
foreach (Shape item in loadedShapesXml) 
{ 
  WriteLine($"{item.GetType().Name} is {item.Colour} and has an
  area of {item.Area}"); 
}
```

This is what your output should look like when you run the application:

```
Loading shapes from XML:
Circle is Red and has an area of 19.6349540849362
Rectangle is Blue and has an area of 200
Circle is Green and has an area of 201.061929829747
Circle is Purple and has an area of 475.2915525616
Rectangle is Blue and has an area of 810
```

I have made a Shape class with Circle and Rectangle class that inherit from it.

```
class Shape
{
    public readonly double Area;
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    Area = Radius* Radius * Math.PI;
}

class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    Area = Width * Height;
}
```

I am unsure why the inherited Area field is not recognized by my Circle and Rectangle classes. Is it because Circle and Rectangle should somehow be incorporate into just one Shape class?

Edit:
This documentation helped me find the answer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties

Comment: Any errors or other output?

Comment: Your question is vague, but you are probably getting an error like "The name 'Area' does not exist in the current context" and/or "Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. A statement like `Area = Width * Height;` is not legal outside of a method. Your base class declares a readonly field, not a property. More likely the book wants you to leave it out of the base class (or declare it `abstract`) and then have in the derived classes e.g. `public double Area => Radius * Radius * Math.PI;`

Comment: When you get a compiler error you **must** share what it is.

Answer (score 2):

First, `public readonly double Area;` is not a property. This is a field. To make a read-only property, you would create a getter-only property like this: `public double Area { get; }`

Next, I'm pretty sure `Area = Radius* Radius * Math.PI;` will result in a compiler error. If you need to override the implementation of Area, I'd make Area a virtual property in your parent class, then override it in your subclass as follows:

```
class Shape
{
    public virtual double Area { get;}
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public override double Area
    {
        get { return Radius * Radius * Math.PI; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You're trying to assign to Area but you've declared it readonly in your base class.

2) The following...

```
Area = Radius* Radius * Math.PI;
```

...is a statement but not a declaration.

It needs to go in *some sort* of method.

The rest of the work is left to the reader. The following merely illustrates placing a statement in a method, which is part of what's at stake.

```
class Circle : Shape
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }

    void DoSomething()
    {    
       //Assume Radius has a value at this point...
       Area = Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
    }
 }
```